# Combining Source code together

Tags: c, dll

I have two pieces of source code for two dll files. They both work individually, but i need them to be put into one dll file.

The first source is here: http://pastebin.com/vqtNLca8

The second source is here: http://pastebin.com/yvFPEMkf

How can i make this one dll file?

Answer (score 1):

Pass them both to LINK.EXE when you build the DLL.

You'll also want to disable one of the `DllMain` definitions, to avoid a symbol multiply defined error.